# Using ReactJs with express and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

So I'm building my first single page app with react, and it's going well so far.
I'm using create-react-app to build and run the app I'm building, and now I arrived to the part which I need to interact with a Server side.

so when I tried to find the way to build an express with socket.io server, I couldn't find how to do it so the create-react-app will build it to.

so my questions is this -

How can I create a server side and compile it throug the create-react-app?
or on the other hand, how can I integrate socket.io and react app on create-react-app?

thanks,

Eilon

Comment: `create-react-app` creates your frontend code. You probably want a separate project for the backend, or at least to exclude your backend code from the `webpack` process.

Comment: Yea but my react code is supposed to get data from the server, so how can i send the data to the code after I build the react app? @erbridge

Comment: Using HTTP requests or WebSocket messages.